# Css Button Animation Issue

Tags: html, css

I have a toggle like this:

[image]

If I click this it will be going like left to right and it goes left but I want left to right no-repeat

Here's my code:

```css
.main-toggle {
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  background-color: grey;
}

.sub-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  top: 13px;
  background-color: black;
}

.sub-toggle:focus {
  -webkit-animation-name: run;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes run {
  50% {
    left: 20%;
  }
```

```html
<button class="main-toggle">
  <button class="sub-toggle"></button>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use transition instead of an animation. Furthermore you shouldn't nest `button` tags - use a `div` instead for the outer toggle.

**Working example:**

```css
.main-toggle {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  background-color: grey;
}

.sub-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  top: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: left 1s;
}

.sub-toggle:focus {
  left: 135px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-toggle">
  <button class="sub-toggle"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and add `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards` to your focus class. Read more about fill-mode [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode). There are some other transition properties and MDN has made some fantastic demos for all of them. Check those out [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations).